# Difference between ng-click and on-touch in ionic 1 framework

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

which click event is best in ionic HTML page?

I had developed ionic 1 framework. I had used ng-click and on-touch on the HTML page.

ng-click code:

```
<ion-floating-button ng-click ="vm.addExpense()" has-footer="false" icon="ion-plus" iconColor="#fff">
```

on-touch code:

```
<ion-floating-button on-touch="vm.addnewCharge()" has-footer="false" button-color="rgb(84, 44, 99)" icon="ion-plus" iconColor="#fff">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference according to the docs is that on-touch fires immediately on touch and does not wait for the release event.

> Called immediately when the user first begins a touch. This gesture
>   does not wait for a touchend/mouseup.

Here's a reference to the docs:
http://ionicn.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/onTouch/

ng-click is definitely the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

ng-click is the way to go with ionic and it will take care of the touch/click 300ms-delay. The Ionic devs have put a lot of work in this to be so simple.

So no need to use the external module ngTouch

http://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-huge-update/431 -- see the paragraph with Adamclick!